# Why do I get a 405 GET not allowed when I am sending a POST request?

Tags: flask, cross-domain

I am sending the POST request from Android to my server (python/Flask)

```
URL url = new URL("www.xxx.com/yyy");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(httpCon.getOutputStream());
out.write(bytes);
out.flush();
out.close();
int status = httpCon.getResponseCode();
...
```

and I receive this with Flask

```
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/yyy', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(headers=['Content-Type'])
@def get_checkpoint_config():
    # ...
```

First **strange** thing : sometimes the server logs

```
WARNING:tornado.access:405 GET /yyy
```

but it is a POST !

There is **a little more strange** to that : some other times I don't get the 405 but `request.data` is **empty**.

I suspect something is fishy with the CORS config. I replaced `@cross_origin` by `@crossdomain(origin='*')` (from this [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/)) but I had the same behaviour

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but fortunately my requests were not too big so I put the data as a GET parameter and I could remove everything related with `cors` (Fask's cross origin extension) and it worked. The question still remains.